# How to get Request Sending Server Domain Name In CURL?

Tags: php, magento, curl

I need to post the some data's from one server `(Server-1)` to another server `(Server-2)` using CURL.
In this case i need to get the request post server domain name in `server-2`.

So how to get the request post domain name `(server-1)` in `Server-2`?

Is any in-build methods are available in CURL?

Any Help Much appreciated.

Sample :

**Server-1**
http://domain1.com

```
                $serviceUrl = 'http://domain1.com/data';
                $curl = curl_init($serviceUrl);

                $curlPostData = array("data" => $data);

                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPostData);

                $curlResponse = curl_exec($curl);

                curl_close($curl);
```

**Server-2**
http://domain2.com

```
<?php

                $data = $_POST['data'];

                //I need to get the http://domain1.com using curl or php?

                // Some Code Process

                ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you define your question a bit more? Some example code maybe?

Comment: Hi all, i have edited my question with sample code. please look it and can you help me this issues?

Comment: I saw your update now. Where does the server1 connect to server2? Do you simply want to monitor where post requests to server2 comes from?

Comment: Yes, Absolutely, i need to monitor the post request domain name in server-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the request server url along with the data

Comment: i want to find the Server-1 Domain name in Server-2 using Php or curl.i don't need to hardcode in request post Server.

Comment: Hi    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] gives you current server name so you can pass url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] from server one and you will get that in server two .

Answer (score 2):

I dont really get your question. You just need to say the refering domain is server-1? 
in that case you can do the following in a bash script:

```
curl -X POST -e 'http://domain1.com' --data 'key=value&anotherkey=anothervalue' http://domain2.com
```

Or you need data from that server? How would you retrieve this data in that case? And where will the request be sendt from?

Comment: Yes, i know this method. But i don't need to send the domain name like this. So please suggest me another solution?

Answer (score 1):

On the server That retrieves the post request, use the php `$_SERVER` variable to read headers.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

`$post = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];` or '$post = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']'
Depending on what you want.

You could also define an attribute when you send the request and retrive it like: '$_POST['myattr']'

I hope this helps, but your question is still kinda sloppy so I dont know if this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: The chrome extension "Postman", is a good way to test POST requests.

Comment: Hi i have tried both the above which you have mentioned, But No luck. Not working for me.

Comment: How did you try it? Give us some code to work with here to understand better/