# Get client's domain name using php

Tags: php, curl

I have problem with getting domain name using `HTTP_REFERER.`
The condition is like this:

http://www.example.com send a curl post to my server. The things is, example.com does not send their url in `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_REFERER)`. So is it possible on my server side to get their domain name ?

Thanks a lot for helping me

My code so far:

---

on abc.com side

```
$data = array('username' => $username ,
              'email' => $email,
              'phone' => $phone );

    $string = http_build_query($data);
    // For debugging purpose
    // echo $string;

    $ch =  curl_init("http://localhost/test/str_pos.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    header("Location: str_pos.php");
```

---

On my server side:

```
$domain = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    if (isset($domain['host'])) {

        echo $domain['host'];
    }
    else{
        echo "No host found";
    }
```

Comment: show your code. what you have done so far?

Comment: @urfusion my code so far as state on my question there. Thanks !

Comment: Does this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949641/how-to-get-request-sending-server-domain-name-in-curl) ask a similar question? Or am I way off the mark here?

Comment: @Spyder_Says_hi so if the abc.com does not send thier url in the parameter, seems like my server side cannot get the domain name based on the request ?

Comment: You can use `var_dump` to show `$_SERVER` and try to find it there.

Comment: Yeah, already get it. Thanks a lot @MartinHeralecký !

Comment: Both question and answer here are so confused and misleading that it's better to delete the entire post  altogether

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would advise a different command. Instead of `HTTP_REFERER` try `HTTP_HOST` or `SERVER_NAME`.

Example:

`$domain = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`

`$domain = parse_url($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);`

> `HTTP_REFERER` - The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify `HTTP_REFERER` as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.
>
> Source http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Check out the following threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459739/php-serverhttp-host-vs-serverserver-name-am-i-understanding-the-ma) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404811/php-get-domain-name).

Comment: This answer is directly opposite to what is asked. Which is the hostname of the client, not server.